# decrypt excel files

Tags: python, excel, apache-poi

Hi I have 1000 encrypted workbooks which I would like to decrypt by providing a pwd.
I could not find a decrypt method under apache poi or python's xlrd module.

Does anyone know a library which could handle this (`wbc.decrypt(pwd)`). I would prefer a lib i could you use from a unix box.

Thanks

Comment: How are the files encrypted? Some intrinsic mechanism to excel, or some external tool?

Comment: just excel encryption. when you open them excel prompts for a pwd.
I do have the pwds. The prob is i have 1000 files so i "only" need a library that handles opening a wbk by providing a pwd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the COM bindings to call the `Unprotect` method.

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

workbook = excel.Workbooks.open(r'c:\mybook.xls', 'password')

workbook.SaveAs('unencrypted.xls')
```

SaveAs can apply a new password. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: thnks will give mono and .net a try

Comment: No need to use mono and .net. Python will do it by itself on Win32.

Comment: That is indeed an issue.  Can you do it in VBA inside of excel?  The code won't be much more complex.

Comment: the files are located on a unix box which i access vi sshfs. Will give mono a try. If not i will use our code a virtual win box. Tanks. Mac ironpython+win32 is off-topic i think. Will google

Comment: I fear that the suggested answer is referring to the "protection" that stops a user from (example) accidentally deleting formulas. This allows viewing the workbook. It is quite different to requiring a password to open the XLS file. Perhaps both the questioner and the answerer could check through this: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/spreadsheet_protection_faq1/

Comment: works thnks. just used a winbox. 
for open its execel.Workbooks.open(r'filepath','password')
Hope that xlrd may support this once

Answer (score 1):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) can read encrypted excel files for you, and write them out decrypted. See the [Encryption](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) page to get started.

Answer (score 0):

As this question and its accepted answer is quite old, I'll share what I use nowadays to decrypt password-protected files for those arriving from Google/etc.

`msoffcrypto` [(PyPI link)](https://pypi.org/project/msoffcrypto-tool/) is a more modern tool for doing this without relying on the win32 API and is consequently platform independent.

This example function should return a decrypted office file as a `BytesIO` object you can then work with as though it were a regular file. (E.g. load into Pandas with `pd.read-excel(decrypted_workbook)`, save to disk, etc.)

```py
def decrypt_office_file(filename: Path, password: str = None) -> io.BytesIO:
    decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
        office_file.load_key(password=password)
        office_file.decrypt(decrypted_file)  # puts result into decrypted_workbook
    return decrypted_workbook
```

You could also expand on this to check if something is actually encrypted with:

```
if office_file.is_encrypted():
    ...
```

Office supports several encryption methods these days including key files (.pem) etc. and this library will manage *most* of them as of this writing.