# openpyxl: password protect entire excel file (xlsx)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, password-protection

I am trying to find pythonic ways to encrypt/password-protect excel xlsx files. Came across openpyxl, where in their documentation (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html) states that it can do so.

However, an error message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'workbookPassword'` is prompted when I executed the following. Help anyone?

```
from openpyxl import workbook

file = 'test.xlsx' // an existing xlsx
wb = load_workbook(filename = file)

wb.security.workbookPassword = 'test_password'
wb.security.lockStructure = True
```

Edit:
I believe I have used the function improperly, though it is not v clear in their documentation. It was also mentioned that the password can be set using this function `openpyxl.workbook.protection.WorkbookProtection.workbookPassword()`, which then differs in their example.

Comment: Check the version of openpyxl you're using.

Comment: I just installed it today, so its the latest. Just checked too

Comment: `from openpyxl import __version__
__version__
'2.5.10'
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("Openpyxl Test.xlsx")
wb.security.workbookPassword = "hshs"`

Comment: Thank you. I have checked and it appears that the most current version is 2.5.9? Tried specifying the version to install to be 2.5.10 but that failed... Appreciate if you can clarify?

Comment: It's my local dev version but not relevant. I was just demonstrating that the code works as expected and the problem must be with your install.

Comment: Even I get the same error message as OP with version 3.0.9. Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: @Jake - Can I know how did you solve this issue? I get the same exact error

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about ways to "encrypt/password-protect excel xlsx files" in a synonymous manner. However, please note that regarding MS Office these are **not** the same (although one may argue about the wording here)! This can be seen from the screenshot below, or simply open an excel file and go to "File", then under Permissions click on "Protect Workbook".

[Screenshot Excel Protection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukDC6.png)

The workbookPassword from openpyxl only prevents modifications of the workbook **structure**. Their documentation states, that this is only meant

> To prevent other users from viewing hidden worksheets, adding, moving,
>   deleting, or hiding worksheets, and renaming worksheets, you can
>   protect the **structure** of your workbook with a password.

See also their documentation [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html).

This only refers to the structure, i.e. to adding/removing sheets, but it explicitly does not forbid users from reading the file, nor from editing the contents of the (already available) sheets! However, the set password does not offer read protection in the sense of an encryption.

I have not found a way to actually encrypt an Excel file with openpyxl, but other packages might do just that. I know encrypted files can be decrypted using Python, see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450530/decrypt-excel-files). Therefore, I am guessing you can also encrypt such files in a similar way, although sadly right now I cannot test this.